# How Do I install specific version of netCore on redhat linux

Tags: linux, yum, rhel

I'm trying to install an specific version of netcore on Redhat but doesn't matter which strategy I use I'm ever getting the latest version of the package.

For example if I run:

yumdownloader --resolve  rh-dotnet20-dotnet-0:**2.0.0-4**.el7.x86_64  --nogpgcheck

It will download:

(1/11): rh-dotnet20-dotnet-2.0.0-4.el7.x86_64.rpm                                         | 4.3 kB  00:00:00
(2/11): libunwind-1.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                    |  57 kB  00:00:00
(3/11): rh-dotnet20-dotnet-host-2.0.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                    | 172 kB  00:00:00
(4/11): libicu-50.1.2-15.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                   | 6.9 MB  00:00:00
(5/11): rh-dotnet20-dotnet-runtime-2.0-2.0.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                             |  20 MB  00:00:01
(6/11): rh-dotnet20-libcurl-7.47.1-1.3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                     | 248 kB  00:00:00
(7/11): rh-dotnet20-lttng-ust-2.8.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                      | 233 kB  00:00:00
(8/11): rh-dotnet20-runtime-2.0-6.el7.x86_64.rpm                                          | 1.1 MB  00:00:00
(9/11): rh-dotnet20-userspace-rcu-0.9.2-3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                  |  89 kB  00:00:00
(10/11): scl-utils-20130529-18.el7_4.x86_64.rpm                                           |  24 kB  00:00:00
(11/11): rh-dotnet20-dotnet-sdk-2.0-2.0.3-4.el7.x86_64.rpm                                |  34 MB  00:00:03

Which is the same if I run:

yumdownloader --resolve  rh-dotnet20-dotnet-0:**2.0.6-1**.el7.x86_64  --nogpgcheck

(1/11): rh-dotnet20-dotnet-2.0.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                         | 5.1 kB  00:00:00
(2/11): rh-dotnet20-dotnet-host-2.0.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                    | 172 kB  00:00:00
(3/11): libunwind-1.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                    |  57 kB  00:00:00
(4/11): libicu-50.1.2-15.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                   | 6.9 MB  00:00:01
(5/11): rh-dotnet20-dotnet-runtime-2.0-2.0.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                             |  20 MB  00:00:01
(6/11): rh-dotnet20-libcurl-7.47.1-1.3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                     | 248 kB  00:00:00
(7/11): rh-dotnet20-lttng-ust-2.8.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                      | 233 kB  00:00:00
(8/11): rh-dotnet20-runtime-2.0-6.el7.x86_64.rpm                                          | 1.1 MB  00:00:00
(9/11): rh-dotnet20-userspace-rcu-0.9.2-3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                  |  89 kB  00:00:00
(10/11): rh-dotnet20-dotnet-sdk-2.0-2.0.3-4.el7.x86_64.rpm                                |  34 MB  00:00:01
(11/11): scl-utils-20130529-18.el7_4.x86_64.rpm                                           |  24 kB  00:00:00

Is there a way to force YUM to install the specific version that I need? Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151690) answer over on Unix? - This question isn't strictly about programming so you may want to migrate it yourself.

Comment: yes, I use that answer for get an idea about which command should I use. But anyway you have reason I should move this question to Unix.

Comment: see my comment above - this looks more like a setup and installation issue rather than a programming issue. If you where trying to do this via script or some other automatic process i'd say yes, but I *personally* feel its off-topc here. If not Unix then SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

The two commands do not have the same effect.  One commend downloads `rh-dotnet20-dotnet-2.0.0-4.el7.x86_64.rpm`, the other one downloads `rh-dotnet20-dotnet-2.0.6-1.el7.x86_64`.

However, the specified version does not extend to the dependencies which are automatically installed.  So if you want `rh-dotnet20-dotnet-host` in version `2.0.0-4.el7`, you need to specify that version explicitly as well.